# Anbox doesn't work Ubuntu 18.04 - cannot find libgtk3-nocsd.so.0

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, anbox

I have installed Anbox but when I use `anbox.appmgr` I get this message

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded
  (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
[ 2018-07-10 12:38:58] [daemon.cpp:59@Run] Application manager service is not running yet
```

I found what I thought was a [solution on the web](https://thomasmodeneis.wordpress.com/2017/09/20/how-to-fix-error-ld-so-object-libgtk3-nocsd-so-0-from-ld_preload-cannot-be-preloaded-cannot-open-shared-object-file-ignored/) but it doesn't work either because when I put this command into my terminal

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ |grep libgtk3
```

it returns

```
-rwSr--r--  1 root root    26616 Mar  3 08:46 libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

also if I do

```
$ wl libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

I get:

```
bin: /usr/bin
bin: /usr/sbin
bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
bin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
bin: /usr/lib
bin: /bin
bin: /sbin
bin: /etc
bin: /lib
bin: /lib64
bin: /usr/games
bin: /usr/local/bin
bin: /usr/local/sbin
bin: /usr/local/etc
bin: /usr/local/lib
bin: /usr/local/games
bin: /usr/include
bin: /usr/local
bin: /usr/share
bin: /opt/wine-stable/bin
bin: /snap/bin
man: /usr/share/man/vi
man: /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1
man: /usr/share/man/pl.UTF-8
man: /usr/share/man/pl
man: /usr/share/man/ru
man: /usr/share/man/de.UTF-8
man: /usr/share/man/fi
man: /usr/share/man/sr
man: /usr/share/man/man8
man: /usr/share/man/id
man: /usr/share/man/nl
man: /usr/share/man/zh_CN
man: /usr/share/man/it
man: /usr/share/man/ko
man: /usr/share/man/es
man: /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8
man: /usr/share/man/man1
man: /usr/share/man/tr
man: /usr/share/man/zh_TW
man: /usr/share/man/ja
man: /usr/share/man/hu
man: /usr/share/man/man7
man: /usr/share/man/man5
man: /usr/share/man/fr
man: /usr/share/man/sv
man: /usr/share/man/pt
man: /usr/share/man/pt_BR
man: /usr/share/man/man4
man: /usr/share/man/de
man: /usr/share/man/cs
man: /usr/share/man/man6
man: /usr/share/man/man3
man: /usr/share/man/da
man: /usr/share/man/man2
man: /usr/share/man/sl
man: /usr/share/info
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62
src: /usr/src/googletest
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.17.0-041700
src: /usr/src/anbox-1
src: /usr/src/googletest/googlemock
src: /usr/src/googletest/googletest
src: /usr/src/virtualbox-5.2.10
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.17.0-041700-generic
libgtk3-nocsd.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

or

```
$ wl anbox
bin: /usr/bin
bin: /usr/sbin
bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
bin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
bin: /usr/lib
bin: /bin
bin: /sbin
bin: /etc
bin: /lib
bin: /lib64
bin: /usr/games
bin: /usr/local/bin
bin: /usr/local/sbin
bin: /usr/local/etc
bin: /usr/local/lib
bin: /usr/local/games
bin: /usr/include
bin: /usr/local
bin: /usr/share
bin: /opt/wine-stable/bin
bin: /snap/bin
man: /usr/share/man/vi
man: /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1
man: /usr/share/man/pl.UTF-8
man: /usr/share/man/pl
man: /usr/share/man/ru
man: /usr/share/man/de.UTF-8
man: /usr/share/man/fi
man: /usr/share/man/sr
man: /usr/share/man/man8
man: /usr/share/man/id
man: /usr/share/man/nl
man: /usr/share/man/zh_CN
man: /usr/share/man/it
man: /usr/share/man/ko
man: /usr/share/man/es
man: /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8
man: /usr/share/man/man1
man: /usr/share/man/tr
man: /usr/share/man/zh_TW
man: /usr/share/man/ja
man: /usr/share/man/hu
man: /usr/share/man/man7
man: /usr/share/man/man5
man: /usr/share/man/fr
man: /usr/share/man/sv
man: /usr/share/man/pt
man: /usr/share/man/pt_BR
man: /usr/share/man/man4
man: /usr/share/man/de
man: /usr/share/man/cs
man: /usr/share/man/man6
man: /usr/share/man/man3
man: /usr/share/man/da
man: /usr/share/man/man2
man: /usr/share/man/sl
man: /usr/share/info
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62
src: /usr/src/googletest
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.17.0-041700
src: /usr/src/anbox-1
src: /usr/src/googletest/googlemock
src: /usr/src/googletest/googletest
src: /usr/src/virtualbox-5.2.10
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic
src: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.17.0-041700-generic
anbox: /snap/bin/anbox.collect-bug-info /snap/bin/anbox.android-settings /snap/bin/anbox.appmgr /snap/bin/anbox
```

In short, it seems Anbox is having trouble locating `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` for it to work when it is showing in my system.

Comment: I can't find the `wl` command in order to run it and compare your results of `wl anbox`. What are the results of `which wl`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why anbox.appmgr is not running is not related to the message about *libgtk3-nocsd.so.0*.

Instead you need to make sure that:

1. The necessary kernel drivers are installed. You can test this by running:

   ```
   ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}
   ```

   and if these are missing, do the kernel module install process as described in https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_kernel_modules.html
2. The necessary snap container is running. You can test this by running:

   ```
   snap services
   ```

   and if *anbox.container-manager* is listed as inactive, start it by:

   ```
   sudo snap start anbox.container-manager
   ```